# Mui Styled Components Issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```js
const Menubar = () => {
  const [anchorElement, setAnchorElement] = useState(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const ElementsContainerBox = styled(Box)({
    display: "flex",
    gap: "15px",
    alignItems: "center",
  });

  const CustomMenuBar = styled(TextField)(({ theme }) => ({
    "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
      height: "32px",
      borderRadius: "14px",
      boxShadow: "0px 0px 3px black",
      outline: "none",
    },
  }));

  const MenuItemsBox = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
    borderRadius: "10px",
    boxShadow: "1px 0px 3px 1px lightgrey",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    background: "#c0c1c0",
  }));

  const handleOpenProfile = (e) => {
    setAnchorElement(e.currentTarget);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar className="navbar">
          <ElementsContainerBox>
            <Box sx={{ display: { sm: "block", md: "none" } }}>
              <IconButton>
                <MenuRounded />
              </IconButton>
            </Box>

            <Box>
              <img className="auctioneer-logo" src={auctioneer_logo} />
            </Box>

            <Box>
              <CustomMenuBar
                placeholder="search"
                InputProps={{
                  startAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="start">
                      {" "}
                      <Search />{" "}
                    </InputAdornment>
                  ),
                }}
              />
            </Box>
          </ElementsContainerBox>

          <ElementsContainerBox sx={{ display: { xs: "none", sm: "none", md: "flex" } }}>
            <Box>
              <Link to="/about-us" className="link-tag">
                <Typography> About us </Typography>
              </Link>
            </Box>

            <Box>
              <Link to="contact-us" className="link-tag">
                <Typography> Contact Us </Typography>
              </Link>
            </Box>

            <Box>
              <Link className="link-tag">
                <Typography> Categories </Typography>
              </Link>
            </Box>
          </ElementsContainerBox>

          <ElementsContainerBox>
            <MenuItemsBox>
              <IconButton>
                {" "}
                <ShoppingBag />{" "}
              </IconButton>
            </MenuItemsBox>

            <MenuItemsBox>
              <IconButton onClick={handleOpenProfile}>
                {" "}
                <Person />{" "}
              </IconButton>
            </MenuItemsBox>

            <IconButton sx={{ display: { xs: "block", md: "none" }, alignItems: "center" }}>
              {" "}
              <MoreVert />{" "}
            </IconButton>
          </ElementsContainerBox>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>

      <Menu anchorEl={anchorElement} open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <MenuItem
          onClick={() => {
            navigate("/login");
            setOpen(false);
          }}
        >
          {" "}
          Login{" "}
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem
          onClick={() => {
            navigate("/register");
            setOpen(false);
          }}
        >
          {" "}
          Register{" "}
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
};

export default Menubar
```

This is my basic menubar code. The issue I am facing is while I am running this code on client side, although everything is working as intended Menu Item is not being rendered correctly where it should be aka below the profile Icon which is located at the extreme right side of the menubar but the menu Popup appears on complete opposite side and I have also checked from the log I appear to be getting some error: AnchorEL prop provided to the component is invalid. Anchor element should be part of the document layout.

I believe the issue is with the styled components I am using and the anchor element is being rendered inside of it because if I bring my IconButton (containing Profile Icon) outside the scope of any custom styled Components I created then this issue is resolved but of course that means my layout gets messed up.

Any help would be appreciated what I am doing wrong. On a side note, I have also tried using useRef but no luck

Need to trigger Menu at its rightful place below the targeted anchor element i.e Profile Icon

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is an issue with event, can you try by updating the handleOpenProfile() method like this:

```
const handleOpenProfile = () => {
    if(anchorElement === null) {
      setAnchorElement(event.currentTarget);
      setOpen(true);
    } else {
      setAnchorElement(null);
      setOpen(false);
    }
};
```

Also then you can adjust anchor origin in menu something like this:

```
<Menu ..........
  getContentAnchorEl={null}
  anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'center', horizontal: 'right'}}
  transformOrigin={{vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'left'}}>
```

You can also try popover component:
https://v4.mui.com/components/popover/